How to get gtk3 to work with gstreamer 1.24.9 on macOS?
I have the gstreamer 1.29.4 Framework installed on macOS which according to the release notes includes gst-plugins-good which includes gtkglsink and gtksink.
None of the gstreamer tutorials that use either gtkglsink or gtksink can find them. Basic Tutorial 5 compiles but fails. Other gstreamer basic and playback tutorials compile and run as they are documented.
Note: the basic gnome gtk demos also work. For example helloworld compiles and runs.
I have the following env and path set:
export  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/pkgconfig

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/lib/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk+3/3.24.42/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gtk4/4.14.4/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2024.1/share/pkgconfig/

After successfully compiling using the following:
gcc basic-tutorial-5.c -o basic-tutorial-5 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0 gstreamer-1.0`

When I try to run the executable I get the following error:
Could not create gtkglsink, falling back to gtksink.

(basic-tutorial-5:85605): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:41:41.095: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
Not all elements could be created.

Questions: is GTK3 and gtkglsink and gtksink actually included with gstreamer 1.24.9? If it is why can't I access it? Why can't I find gtkglsink or gtksink?
I've asked this question on both GStreamer and GTK discourse and the feedback I get is "you have to have the gtk3 plug-on installed". No one is willing to tell me or point me to how to do that, only "search online for it".
If it's not located in either the gstreamer 1.24.9 macOS framework or in the gtk3 package installed with homebrew -- where can I find it and how can I install it?
Can I just build the files located here and set an environement variable to point to my "custom plug-ins"?
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/tree/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-good/tests/examples/gtk

If yes, how do I do that? Is there a meson build command someone can suggest I use?
Any help would be appreciated. This process has been very frustrating and I would really like to be able to do more and explore using gtk with gstreamer on my mac. Thank you!

It looks like brew installs the gstreamer plugins along with gstreamer.  I would try setting GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH or GST_PLUGIN_PATH to the appropriate directory.

gst-inspect-1.0 tells you what plugins are installed.

Thanks to you both for the suggestions. I can confirm that gstreamer does install the plugins for Linux, specifically I tested on Ubuntu, and does NOT on macOS - for either homebrew or Apple Framework.

Testing for most gst-plugin-good without setting the plugin path variable does return info on the plugin. For example: gst-inspect-1.0 osxvideosink returns (among other info):  Long-name                macOS Video sink
Description              macOS native videosinkPlugin Details:
Name                     osxvideo
Description              OSX native video output plugin
Filename                 /Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstosxvideo.dylib
Version                  1.24.9
Source module            gst-plugins-good

But doing these does not: gst-inspect-1.0 gtkglsink
No such element or plugin 'gtkglsink'gst-inspect-1.0 gtksink
No such element or plugin 'gtksink' Any suggestions? Should I rebuild gst-plugin-good as a "custom" plug-in stripping out everything that I don't need except the gtk plugin and point to that? Thanks for any tips

Homebrew's formula does list gtk3 and gtk4 as dependency. So I would expect the sinks to be build as well.. Maybe the plugins got blacklisted because of a dependency error? Homebrew can be crappy at times..
